# fortran -- string won't copy

Tags: string, fortran

I'm trying to make a program which reads a file, splits it into tokens by spaces, and prints out the tokens. For some reason, the strings won't copy into my tokens array,  but it will print the substring just fine in the loop, and I cannot figure out why. The program is below.

```
        implicit none

        integer :: argc, ix, x, io, i, tidx, start
        logical :: exists
        character(len=32) :: filename
        character(len=32), dimension(:), allocatable :: args
        character(len=254) :: iom
        character(len=:), allocatable :: content
        character :: c
        character(len=32), allocatable :: tokens (:)

        argc = command_argument_count()
        if (argc < 1) then
                print *, "usage: k file"
                stop 1
        endif
        allocate(args(argc))
        
        ! collect arguments
        do ix = 1, argc
                call get_command_argument(ix, args(ix))
        end do

        filename = args(1)
        
        ! get file size
        inquire(file=filename, exist=exists, size=x, iostat=io, iomsg=iom)
        if (.not.exists) then
                print *, "File ",filename," not found. Aborting."
                stop 2
        elseif (io.ne.0) then
                print *, iom
                stop 3
        endif

        ! allocate the content buffer to read into
        allocate(character(len=x) :: content)

        ! read file
        open(unit=2, file=filename, status='old', access='stream')
        read(2) content
        close(2)

        ! allocate the token array
        allocate(tokens(256))

        ! scan
        tidx = 1
        start = 1
        i = 1
        do while (i < x)
                if (tidx >= 256) then
                        print *, "'limit"
                        stop 4
                end if

                c = content(i:i)
                if (c.eq.' ') then
                        tokens(tidx) = content(start:i)
                        print '(A)', content(start:i)
                        start = i
                        tidx = tidx + 1
                end if
                i = i + 1
        end do
       
        print *, "tidx: ", tidx
        do i = 1, tidx
                print *, "token: '",tokens(tidx),"'"
        end do
end program k
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `index` function, and if you use (re)-allocation on a assignment, this is not too hard.  Note, the following code destroys `content` and it assumes that CRLF are token separators.

```
program k

   implicit none

   integer :: argc, ix, x, io, i, tidx, start
   logical :: exists
   character(len=32) :: filename
   character(len=32), allocatable :: args(:)
   character(len=254) :: iom
   character(len=:), allocatable :: content
   character :: c
   character(len=32), allocatable :: tokens (:)

   argc = command_argument_count()
   if (argc < 1) then
      print *, "usage: k file"
      stop 1
   endif

   allocate(args(argc))
   
   ! collect arguments
   do ix = 1, argc
      call get_command_argument(ix, args(ix))
   end do

   filename = args(1)
   
   ! get file size
   inquire(file=filename, exist=exists, size=x, iostat=io, iomsg=iom)
   if (.not. exists) then
      print *, "File ",filename," not found. Aborting."
      stop 2
   else if (io .ne. 0) then
      print *, iom
      stop 3
   endif

   ! allocate the content buffer to read into
   allocate(character(len=x) :: content)

   ! read file
   open(unit=2, file=filename, status='old', access='stream')
   read(2) content
   close(2)

   ! Replace '\r' and '\n' with ' '.
   do i = 1, len(content)
      ix = iachar(content(i:i))
      if (ix == 10 .or. ix == 13) content(i:i) = ' '
   end do

   ! Burn any leading spaces and check that at least one token exists.
   content = adjustl(content)
   if (len_trim(content) == 0) then
      print *, 'Empty file?'
      stop 4
   end if

   ! allocate the token array, and initialize all to zero length
   allocate(tokens(256))
   tokens = ''

   ! scan
   do tidx = 1, 256
      i = index(content, ' ')
      tokens(tidx) = content(1:i-1)
      content = adjustl(content(i+1:))
      print '(A)', tokens(tidx)
      if (len_trim(content) == 0) exit
   end do
end program k
```